# How can i implement multi touch gestures in codenameone?

Tags: java, codenameone

I want to implement the multi touch gestures events in codenameone. I used 
    `@Override
    public void pointerPressed(int x, int y)`

I log x,y and I logcat the .apk file with adb.
when you touch a the display it shows x,y of the point but when the second finger and other fingers touched the display nothing showed and nothing touched there is no such a new pointerpreesed happen how can i implement multi touch gestures events with such a thing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codename One supports pointer* events that accepts `int[]` as the argument. Same signature as above only with two arrays e.g.:

```
public void pointerPressed(int[] x, int[] y)
public void pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y)
public void pointerReleased(int[] x, int[] y)
```

You can also override the pinch method to capture that specific gesture: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/in-a-pinch

Comment: Thank you so much. public void pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y) shows array of pointer but pressed and released doesn't. I don't find anything related to pinch that i override it where it is can u make example for that.

Comment: Pinch is in a specific component. Some platforms only send the single argument pressed/released event which makes sense since you are always removing/placing one finger at a time (even if it doesn't feel like it).

Comment: my problem is that pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y) is worked but pointerPressed(int[] x, int[] y) and pointerReleased(int[] x, int[] y)  doesn't work.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem for most gestures, just override both versions of pointer pressed/released and take into consideration that the thing that matters with multi touch is the multi finger motion.